# Show static banner or category banner on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, if

I have the following code in `product/view.phtml`:

```
<?php 
    if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
    $_category=Mage::registry('current_category');
    $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        $_imgHtml   = '';
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
            $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'"     alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }?>

    <?php if($_imgUrl) { ?>
    <!-- Category has Image uploaded -->
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <!-- Category has NO Image uploaded, show static block -->
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_top_banner')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php }?>
<?php endif;?>
```

This currently shows either the category banner or a static banner if the category does not currently have a banner. However, if I visit the product page directly then no banner is displayed.

Can anyone please suggest an edit to the code so that if a user visits a product directly (i.e. not by visiting a category) then the static banner ('cms_top_banner') will be displayed.

Comment: That is because Mage::registry('current_category') contain value when you browse products from category page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, when you are loading your product page directly, `Mage::registry('current_category')` will return `NULL` and thus nothing will get executed in your code, since all of your code resides in that parent if loop checking.

You can use below code.

```
<?php
    $_imgHtml = '';
    $_imgUrl  = false;

    //check whether a valid category exist
    if(Mage::registry('current_category')) {

        //grabing category banner if any
        $_category=Mage::registry('current_category');
        $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {

            //prepare banner html
            $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'"     alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }
    }

    //check a valid image url exist
    if ($_imgUrl) {
            echo $_imgHtml;
    } else {
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
            ->setBlockId('cms_top_banner')
            ->toHtml();
    }
?>
```

This will make sure, if a valid category does not exist, it will show your default banner in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
        $_category=Mage::registry('current_category');
        $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        $_imgHtml   = '';
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) :
            $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'"     alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        endif;?>
      <?php if($_imgUrl) : ?>
        <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
      <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_top_banner')->toHtml(); ?>
      <?php endif;?>
<?php else:?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_top_banner')->toHtml(); ?> 
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hi Minesh, I receive an unexpected 'endif' error with the code above.

Comment: @YorkieMagento just updated code please check

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, it will show static banner if there is no category:

```
<?php
    if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
        $_category=Mage::registry('current_category');
        $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        $_imgHtml   = '';
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
            $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'"     alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }
?>
        <?php if($_imgUrl) { ?>
            <!-- Category has Image uploaded -->
            <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <!-- Category has NO Image uploaded, show static block -->
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_top_banner')->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php }?>
<?php else: ?>
        <!-- No category available, show static block -->
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cms_top_banner')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Prateek, I receive an unexpected 'endif' error with the code above.

Comment: You might be having that at the end of your code somewhere. Try removing the last endif in above code.